# How can I use text and latex simultaneously in matlab legend?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to set my legend in a Matlab picture as $K_{\text{C}}$, which can be built with *pdflatex* as this:
[image]

When I practice in the Matlab, I use the following code

---

figure
plot(1:10,10:10:100,'ro-');
legend('$K_{C}=200$','interpreter','latex');

---

But I get this result:
[image]

What should I do to achieve my purpose?

Any helpful suggestions and answers will be appreciated.

---

I add the second picture to make the question readily comprehensive.

Comment: Unrelated but please never ever use `\text` for this. It does not do what you think. In this case I'd just use `\mathrm`

Comment: For a simple graph like this, I'd use `matlab` to get the data out and then use `pgfplots` to typeset the entire graph, axis data and legend in LaTeX directly and in the font of your document.

Comment: BTW: what exactly is the problem on the show graph? That `C` is not upright? I already told you you should not be using `\text` in the first place. But other than that I have no idea what `matlab` can do in relation to LaTeX typesetting.

Comment: Thanks! What I want is the upright C. 
Your suggestion is good for me. I will try to use **pdfplots** for simple graphs. 
Cheers!

Comment: The interesting part for me is then why `\text` gives italic in this case. What exactly is `matlab` doing here. BTW: `pgfplots` can also be used for complicated graphs. It is actually really good a plotting external data. I tend to advise our students to always make sure to save the datapoints from `matlab`, `R` whatever. You never know which better plotting software you come across later and then it would be nice to be able to redo the graph using the same data.

Comment: \text will cause errors when I use latex as the interpreter.  
The italic text is obtained by *K_{C}*. 
I agree with the point that with my further study, a better tool may be found for plotting graphs. 
Thanks again.

Comment: The problem is that `\text` is provided by `amstext` which is loaded by `amsmath` but we do not know if `matlab` loads `amsmath` when it is doing LaTeX stuff. It might just be using a compilation mode that ignores errors (silently)

Comment: Ok, I got it. 
Thanks for your patient reply.